# Cannot create deb package

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I am learning to create a deb package, I find this: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html
and follow it

1 `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

2 `wget -O hello-2.7.tar.gz "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.7.tar.gz"`

3 `tar xf hello-2.7.tar.gz
   cd hello-2.7`

4 `./configure
   make 
   make install`

5 starting a package
`bzr dh-make hello 2.7 hello-2.7.tar.gz`

6 `cd hello/debian
   rm *ex *EX`

7 `vi debian/changelog`

> root@vhost100:~/hello/debian# cat changelog
>      hello (2.7-0ubuntu1)  precise; urgency=low
>
> - Initial release (Closes: #nnnn)
>
>   -- root   Tue, 19 Jul 2016 18:28:11 +0800

8 `bzr add debian/source/format
 bzr commit -m "Initial commit of Debian packaging."`

9 `bzr builddeb -- -us -uc`

I got error

> are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling
>   back to the standard locale ("C"). dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build
>   dependencies: autotools-dev dpkg-buildpackage: warning: Build
>   dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting. dpkg-buildpackage:
>   warning: (Use -d flag to override.) debuild: fatal error at line 1350:
>   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed bzr: ERROR: The build
>   failed.

What is wrong?

Comment: I'd guess it could do with `sudo apt-get install autotools-dev dpkg-buildpackage` - I am not an expert, but I think that is what it is looking for. Check they both exist via `apt-cache search autotools-dev` etc first if you like.

Comment: i installed autotools-dev,it is ok,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, it looks like this part of your error was pertinent:

> Unmet build dependencies: autotools-dev dpkg-buildpackage

I had suggested that both of these needed to be installed using `apt-get`, and you found that in fact only the first one was needed.

Pleased it works!